# __float80 size in C++ using GCC compiler, returning 6 more bytes than expected

Tags: c++, gcc

When I use sizeof() on a __float80 variable it returns 16.
I'm compiling with GCC, which supports __float80.
Shouldn't the result be 10? Is there something I'm missing?

```
#include <iostream>
;
int main()
{
  __float80 number = 0;
  std::cout << sizeof(number);
}
```

I expected it to return 10, but it returns 16 instead. Is there a reason an 80-bit float is taking up 128 bits of memory?

Comment: Padding bytes to keep things aligned to a 16-byte boundary, perhaps?

Comment: Are you targeting an x86/x64 platform? If so, [It is an alias for the type name _Float64x on these targets.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html)